# i try to make pie graph on angular and i use Chartjs and i get error when i try run my project

Tags: angular, charts, frontend, chart.js, ng2-charts

code share below:

html

```
<div>
  <canvas baseChart
          [data]="pieChartData"
          [colors]="colors"
          [labels]="pieChartLabels"
          [chartType]="pieChartType"
        >
  </canvas>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrl: './pie-chart.component.css'
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {

  pieChartData: number[] = [350,450,120];
  pieChartLabels: string[] = ['xyz','Logistics','Main st Bakery','Acme hosting'];
  colors: any[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: ['#26547c','#ff6b6b','#ffd166']
    }
  ];
  pieChartType = 'pie'

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){

  }
}
```

i want make pie graph

Answer (score 1):

After going through the [`demo pie chart`](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#PieChart) Below is a working example of pie chart generated through `ng2-charts` package. The following changes were made!

1. `chartType` in HTML needs to be `type` instead.
2. `backgroundColor` need to be set inside the `datasets` array, instead of `colors` attribute in the html
3. `pieChartData` needs to be restructured to contain the datasets within it

code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { ChartData, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgChartsModule],
  template: `
    <div>
      <canvas baseChart
              [data]="pieChartDataFinal"
              [labels]="pieChartLabels"
              [type]="pieChartType"
            >
      </canvas>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  pieChartLabels: string[] = [
    'xyz',
    'Logistics',
    'Main st Bakery',
    'Acme hosting',
  ];
  colors: any[] = [{}];
  public pieChartType: ChartType = 'pie';
  pieChartDataFinal: ChartData<'pie', number[], string | string[]> = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [350, 450, 120],
        backgroundColor: ['#26547c', '#ff6b6b', '#ffd166'],
      },
    ],
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-leleqc?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)